what percentage of utility applications are granted on the first try?
Is this statistic tracked somewhere? If so, what is the percentage utility patent applications are granted on the first try? In other words, no further office actions were requested from the examiner, no rejections etc.?

In my experience all claims get granted on the first try exactly zero percent of the time. In many cases, no claims are granted without editing. This is normal and expected. This is really where the patent attorney earns their fees.

I don't think it is a worthwhile statistic to track at all, largely b/c the scope of the main independent claim can vary so that it is not a useful indicator of either the strictness/laxness of the patent office, nor of the skill of the drafter.

Of over 100 applications I filed as a patent agent I had one with all claims allowed on first action. I worried that the examiner didn’t understand the invention and urged the inventor to file a continuation application to try to get both broader and narrower claims but he was happy with all claims allowed.
There were a few others with some claims allowed on first action.
Some art units are very difficult to get anything allowed period so an average  statistic is not too helpful.

I had one patent attorney explain that if a claim was accepted on the first try, you probably didn’t claim broadly enough. Of course he didn’t mind increasing his billable hours.

I don't think this is a useful metric. I have over a hundred patents worldwide and none of them had all their claims approved on the first office action. In fact this is intentional. Good patent attorneys are trying to get the broadest protection possible. This means broad claims. It is generally thought better to claim too broadly and edit narrower than to claim too narrow and get minimal protection. Patent rejections are all part of the game. In some cases, the examiner is just asking you to explain why prior art isn't relevant. Attorneys know this, but people filing without attorneys often give up way too early.

One thing I had to explain to clients is that a “Final Rejection” was only final until more money was paid to the office.
